# Can we animate multiple objects using a single timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

To animate multiple objects in a view, do we have to use seperate timers for each of the object?

Currently I have four objects for which I am using four timers. How can I do it using a single timer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are animating them all at once within the same time window you can do them together:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"anim1" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

object1.frame = newFrame1;
object2.frame = newFrame2;
object3.frame = newFrame3;
object4.frame = newFrame4;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hey i do not want to use in built animation. Infact i am looking out for a custom  animation.So i want to use NSTimer to call the function repeatedly to animate the objects. Please Help. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are animating at the same time then you should use four timers,else you can use single timer itself.

All the best.

Comment: If we have 100 such objects, should we use hundred timers? I believe using multiple timers affects battery performance and drains the battery.

Comment: do you want to animate 100 set of images (1 set=20 frames of images)simultaneously..